# Compiling FileZilla on OSX

Tags: macos, filezilla, gnutls

I've been trying to compile the FileZilla versions 3.11 and 3.24 on Mac for a research project but when I run ../configure I get the following error:

```
configure: error: libgnutls 3.1.12 greater was not found. You can get it from http://gnutls.org/
```

However, I've installed gnutls using homebrew; when I run

```
brew list gnutls
```

I can see the library installed at /usr/local/Cellar/gnutls/3.5.8/

Any ideas to resolve the problem are appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

It seems that **GNUtls**, as installed by **homebrew** ships with a pkgconfig file. So, you need to install **pkgconfig** if you don't have it already using:

```
brew install pkgconfig
```

Then, once you have that, you can find the compiler include file settings with:

```
pkg-config --cflags gnutls
```

**Sample Output**

```
-I/usr/local/Cellar/gnutls/3.5.8/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/nettle/3.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/libtasn1/4.10/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/p11-kit/0.23.3/include/p11-kit-1
```

And the linker library settings with:

```
pkg-config --libs gnutls
```

**Sample Output**

```
-L/usr/local/Cellar/gnutls/3.5.8/lib -lgnutls
```

So, we (just) need to convey that information to **FileZilla**. So, first we run:

```
./configure --help | grep -i utls
```

**Sample Output**

```
  --enable-gnutlssystemciphers
                          Enables the use of gnutls system ciphers.
  LIBGNUTLS_CFLAGS
              C compiler flags for LIBGNUTLS, overriding pkg-config
  LIBGNUTLS_LIBS
              linker flags for LIBGNUTLS, overriding pkg-config
```

So it looks like we need to do something like:

```
export LIBGNUTLS_CFLAGS=$(pkg-config --cflags gnutls)
export LIBGNUTLS_LIBS=$(pkg-config --libs gnutls)
./configure
```

**Original Answer**

I haven't tried this with **FileZilla**, but I use it with other packages, and there is nothing to lose...

If **homebrew** has installed your GNUtls in `/usr/local/Cellar/gnutls/3.5.8/`, you could try telling **FileZilla** that location in your `configure` like this:

```
./configure CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/Cellar/gnutls/3.5.8/include" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/Cellar/gnutls/3.5.8/lib" ... other flags
```

Comment: Cool - glad it worked for you! We learn something every day. Good luck with your project.